# Storing a list in Hidden field leads to weird results

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, hidden-field

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
return View("Index", new IndexModel { Foo = new List<string>() { "*" });
}
```

where Index.cshtml has a form that contains `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Foo)`

```
public ActionResult ProcessForm(IndexModel model)
{
}
```

Inside the ProcessForm your model.Foo contain a single string which reads:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

I am so confused...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the result if you run `ToString()` on your collection, like `HiddenFor` is doing. You'll need to do something special to make the list into a string.

Here's a quick and dirty Linq statement that will convert it into a comma-separated list:

```
list.Aggregate("", (s,x) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? x : s + ", " + x);
```

Comment: I'll probably convert to JSON instead but your answer unfortunately makes sense.. *sigh*

Comment: Why not just use string.Join(",", list)?

Comment: It's been a year, but if I recall correctly, you don't want to pass null or empty values through. If Join will do that, I agree it would be simpler.